# Is there is an android emulator I can run on a PC with Xeon processor?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, xeon-phi

I have a PC with an Intel Xeon E5630 @ 2.53GHz.

I cannot run Android Studio emulator or Genymotion emulator.

When I tried to run Android Studio emulator, I had this error:

> Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]

After some updates for the motherboard and uninstalling to the emulator and reinstall it, I get those errors:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'pixel_xl_silver'

> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Here is the CPU information:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5630  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x1f
cpu MHz         : 1627.786
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov 
pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdt
scp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cp
uid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xt
pr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp t
pr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida arat flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds 
swapgs
bogomips        : 5066.68
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5630  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x1f
cpu MHz         : 1647.835
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida arat flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs
bogomips        : 5066.68
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5630  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x1f
cpu MHz         : 1725.616
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 9
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 18
initial apicid  : 18
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida arat flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs
bogomips        : 5066.68
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5630  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x1f
cpu MHz         : 1673.013
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 10
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 20
initial apicid  : 20
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida arat flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs
bogomips        : 5066.68
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Could someone help?

Comment: i'm not sure if you'll find an answer for that over here. it might be better to ask your question here: (https://android.stackexchange.com)

Comment: That's a [Westmere-EP CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/47924/intel-xeon-processor-e5630-12m-cache-2-53-ghz-5-86-gt-s-intel-qpi.html).  It's missing [the `abm` feature bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#ABM) because it's old, not because it's a Xeon.  You'd have the same problem with an old desktop Nehalem/Westmere.  (I assume qemu wants tzcnt/lzcnt so it can emulate ARM `clz` more efficiently, instead of using legacy x86 BSF / BSR.)